# google play games testing data was not reset when publishing app

Tags: publish, google-play-games, leaderboard

today is my app release. on iOS everything works fine, but on android i noticed that the testing data of google play game services is still in the leaderboards!

i read that leaderboard data is resetted when publishing a game.. so why is the data still in there? will it take some more hours? (i published 3 hours ago)

or did i do anything wrong? for highscores it's not a problem, but i have a leaderboard called "total hours played" and theres a (wrong) testing data of 1100 hours. if i cannot delete this data it will be on rank 1 forever :(